# Gas line to appliance seized cannot disconnect

Tags: gas

[image]

I have a gas line to a gas range I'm trying to take off. The nuts are very tight. In the photo there are 2 nuts. It looks like the upper one is attached to the gas hose (the flexible hose). Using a very long wrench I'm able to loosen the top nut. But, strangely the hose also spins with the top nut. I expected the top nut to spin freely from the hose. So, loosing the top puts a kink into the gas hose. I'm afraid that the kink will push pressure on the hose and cause a gas leak. What should I do keep spinning the nut with a wrench without destroying the gas hose?

Comment: If the top 2 nuts are turning together, the hose MUST turn.  That's why you need to hold the second nut.

Comment: You need two wrenches. One to turn and one to hold from turning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That top nut is the one to undo, it is not connected to the hose but just stuck to it.

You will need to hold the hose and free the nut.

If you do damage the hose you will have to replace it.

Comment: Exactly correct. You might try spraying some penetrating lube on the top of the nut to help break it free of the tubing.

Answer (score 2):

It will not kink if you undo the other hand first.

Undo the other end of the hose from the appliance and have someone hold it straight from the pipe. Then it doesn’t matter if it turns when you undo the nut from the gas line.

You need two wrenches, one on the top nut and one on the nut just below it, the wrench on the lower nut is to keep it from turning while you turn the wrench on the top nut

Your gas valve is turned off so if you do damage  The flexible line you’re not going to cause a gas leak, you will just need to replace the hose. If the nut is seized to the hose it probably needs to be replaced anyway.